# Change Queued Jobs Order in Windows HPC 2012

Tags: queue, hpc

Is it possible to change the already queued jobs in windows windows hpc 2012?
I need to move some files from the head node before running another queued job to free space for that job.

Answer (score 0):

I found this statement in [Microsoft TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919436(v=ws.11).aspx):

> The order of the job queue is based on job priority level and submit time. Jobs with higher priority levels run before lower priority jobs. The job submit time determines the order within each priority level.

So, as my already queued jobs all are of "Normal" priority, I can set the priority of my move job higher than "Normal" such as "Highest" to get the job done.